# WindowsForm not working correctly?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I'm trying to open a windows form within a loop per-say. When ever it calls upon the method to show the form none of the picture boxes show, and it's a completely blank form.
Any fixes to this? I need it to be within this loop that it calls the formshow method, but I've tried it elsewhere and the form shows perfectly, but I can't exactly use it in the places I put it to debug the problematic spot. Thank you for the help! I'm using C#

```
public override bool OnNewFrame()
{
    for(uint i=0;;i++)
    {
        if (straightcalled == false)
        {
            if (checkform("Form4") == false)
            {
                straightcalled = true;
                showform();
            }
        }       
    }

    return (++newframes < 50000);
}

Form4 newform = new Form4();

private void showform()
{
    newform.Show();
    newform.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    newform.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    newform.TopMost = true;   
}
```

Comment: What is your `showform` method doing. I would guess that is where the problem lies. Can you post that code?  I am also unfamiliar with `OnNewFrame`. Is that part of a library of some sort? Is that something that is called from the UI thread? Is it called by a background worker thread? You also have an infinite loop in your for loop. That is probably part of your issue. (And less someone be pedantic about the loop not being infinite because it will overflow at some point...in the practical sense, it is infinite)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Create a constant `loop` to generate a single `form` one after another? I don't actually see the point-

Comment: I believe the infinite loop is the issue, but the problem isn't within my showform method, because I can call it form anywhere else but the OnNewFrame method. I'm also using Intel's Perceptual Computing SDK, and that is a method within the UtilMPipeline

Comment: Why do you have the loop at all? Can't you just enter the method and check if the form is shown and if not, show it? No loop needed.

Comment: @user2536897 May be the problem is in your `showform` method but you couldn't find that. Kindly show it to us.

Comment: Why dont you define the Length of the loop? What is the code for `showform`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wyMMGvCv

Comment: @user2536897 - The code from the pastebin link is not called `showform`. Is that the method referred to as `showform` in this snip? The `showform` you list here takes a string argument, the method `straight` from your paste takes no arguments.

Comment: Yes, the Method  straight() is really showform.

Comment: @user2536897 - It is hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish. I am very sure your problem is the for loop in the `OnNewFrame`. I don't understand why you have a loop there at all, much less a loop with no exit condition.  Are you attempting to stay in the `OnNewFrame` method until the form is closed? If that is what you are trying to do, then rather than using `Show` for the form, use `ShowDialog` to make it modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you main issue is the loop with no exit condition in the OnNewFrame method. This loop is just consuming CPU and doesn't seem to be accomplishing anything of value.

As I am unsure what your goal is, I am going to make an attempt at solving your issue.  I have not used the Perceptual Computing SDK from Intel, so this is a guess, but hopefully will help to point you in a right direction even if it doesn't solve the issue.  If you need to reuse the dialog or need it to be modeless than this won't solve the issue. Again, unsure as to your goal, but hopefully this helps.

```
public override bool OnNewFrame()
{
    if (straightcalled == false)
    {
        if (checkform("Form4") == false)
        {
            straightcalled = true;
            showform();
        }
    }       

    return (++newframes < 50000);
}

private void showform()
{
    using (Form4 newForm = new Form4())
    {
        newform.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        newform.ShowDialog();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. As for the infinite loops that's what contains the facial recognition code, and since the camera has to constantly update that then that's where the loop comes in, but this fixes my issue with the form!